# Extract URL from string of HTML

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I am trying to extract the URL from the given `String`, which contain the HTTP response with HREF tag.  I have reached the beginning of the links but I need to terminate the string as soon as the HREF ends.  How this could be achieved?

```
public class Extracturl {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line;

    try {
        String u="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/china";
        String fileName = "e:\\test.txt";
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName,true));
        url = new URL(u);
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        String w=new String();
        while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {


                try {
   if(line.contains("href=\"/wiki")&&line.contains("\" />")&& (!line.contains("File")))
                    {   

                    if(!w.contains(line.substring(line.indexOf("href=\"/"))))
                    {w=w+line.substring(line.indexOf("href=\"/"));                        
                        System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf("href=\"/"))); 
                    writer.write(w);
                    writer.newLine();
                    }}
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();

           // writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}

    }
```

I even tried

```
   w=w+line.substring(line.indexOf("href=\"/"),line.indexOf("\">"));
```

But this gave me error.

My aim is to get all the URLs which are linked from the page.

Comment: Use an HTML parser for that purpose.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  Great comment, but I think it would make a better answer.  See [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet before saying don't do this way , tell how this could be done other way .

Comment: Try this example: http://blog.houen.net/java-get-url-from-string/

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was going to do it, but I want to explain this a little bit more in depth in an answer than just stating that. Internet connection is sloppy in the train, so it took me a while.

Comment: *"before saying don't do this way , tell how this could be done other way."*  Before commenting, try reading the answers to the linked question.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an HTML parser for that purpose. Here is an example with the embedded Java HTML parser. There are other alternatives like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), but for basic HTML handling, this one does a pretty good job:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Tag;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;

public class URLExtractor {

    private static class HTMLPaserCallBack extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {

        private Set<String> urls;

        public HTMLPaserCallBack() {
            urls = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        }

        public Set<String> getUrls() {
            return urls;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleSimpleTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
            handleTag(t, a, pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleStartTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
            handleTag(t, a, pos);
        }

        private void handleTag(Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
            if (t == Tag.A) {
                Object href = a.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
                if (href != null) {
                    String url = href.toString();
                    if (!urls.contains(url)) {
                        urls.add(url);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            String u = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/china";
            URL url = new URL(u);
            is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException
            HTMLPaserCallBack cb = new HTMLPaserCallBack();
            new ParserDelegator().parse(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)), cb, true);
            for (String aUrl : cb.getUrls()) {
                System.out.println("Found URL: " + aUrl);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Executed as it is given .. but no output is generated .

Comment: @ratankumar even here from the train it worked (and the connection is really poor)